# Mysql PHP - Select a record when I know its order

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to select a record when I know its order.

Example: I know order is 2 (start is 1) and i want get record have id = 4 (condition is x column = 0)

```
id|name|x|
1 |a   |0|
2 |b   |1|
3 |c   |2|
4 |d   |0|
5 |e   |3|
6 |f   |0|
```

How can i do that thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The whole point of a database is you don't know it's order, if you want the record with id=4 then ask for it WHERE id=4.

Comment: @awiebe I want select by order (i count by myself) example my order is 3 and x = 0 That i want select is id = 6

Comment: In modern development you should not have that case

Comment: in other words - why do you think you need to select by position?

Comment: in my case i must select one record when i know x = 0 (dynamic) and position (with x = 0) = 2 (dynamic). In this example result is record 4 |d   |0|

Comment: **Why** do you need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `limit` to offset your data by 1

```
select *
from your_table
where x = 0
order by id
limit 1, 1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/052af/5)

Comment: I try select *
from my_table
where x = 0
order by name ASC
limit 2, 1   (2 is my order i want) but it return last record :(

Comment: My code works. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/052af/1). The order starts with `0`. `limit 0, 1` would give you the fist record.

Comment: @juergend You may want to order by `id`, since it seems to be an identity column that may actually indicate order. I doubt `name` is sequential other than in the example.